# tinyscroll bar issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html5boilerplate

I have installed tinyScroll onto my not sure whether i haven't installed the tinyScroll Bar plugin correctly or have a css issue, I have noticed that my scroll bar does not work, when i try to scroll through the hidden content. 
[click here](http://iamnatesmithen.com/bodyworks/product-details.php)
Inspect element is not picking up any issues, however i have noticed when when i click on the scroll the class `noSelect`appears. does anyone know what the issue is?

Comment: where you have added tinyscrollbar js ?

Comment: myscroll.js it's at the bottom

Answer (score 1):

It seems your `$('#scrollbar1').tinyscrollbar();` isn't being properly run.

Most likely due to the fact that you call `$('#scrollbar1').tinyscrollbar();` before you have loaded the actual scroll library.

Move `<script src="js/main.js"></script>` to the bottom of the page, rather than the top.

Comment: that was my initial thought, but i've tried that an i'm still not having any joy

Comment: If you notice that you can run in the JS panel on the Chrome Web Editor (right click inspect element) and run $('#scrollbar1').tinyscrollbar(); then the scrollbar kicks in to life. I note you have two document ready section in the main.js, try putting both of the contents into the jQuery(document).ready(function($) { } one.

Comment: cheers mate, again, i've been those subtle changes yet the scroll is still stationary.

Comment: Can you add: $('#scrollbar1').tinyscrollbar(); to the bottom where you have the footer js code as shown in : http://jsfiddle.net/vGMAC/

Comment: Ha, i've made that amend, still no joy... I might just give in on this plugin

Comment: Haha, there isn't any issue with the plugin, it's something else that appears to be breaking it at run time, have you tried the running the JS in the inspect element JS panel, as it works there. Other than playing around with positioning and chaining the JS I'm not sure what to say, sorry ha.

Answer (score 1):

instead of #scrollbar1 try for

```
$('.viewport').tinyscrollbar();
```

Comment: thats strange try to add full js instead of min tinyscroll js

Comment: the tinyscroll js isn't the issue it's just the positioning of the $('#scrollbar1').tinyscrollbar(); as you can tell if you run the $('#scrollbar1').tinyscrollbar(); in the JS inspector.